# How to open links while keeping browser in the background?

Tags: excel, vba, browser

**SCENARIO:**

Opening many links from an Excel workbook using an Excel VBA Macro.

**ISSUE:**

Every time a link is opened it brings the default web browser into focus (in the foreground).

**GOAL:**

Do work on a different application in the foreground while the links open in the background (since they take considerable time to open).

**TRIED SO FAR:**

I thought this would be a simple browser setting but now I'm not sure. For example, in Firefox I tried typing in the address bar ‘about:config’ then changing browser.tabs.loadDivertedInBackground to TRUE but after this Firefox still comes to the front when links are opened (the setting just makes it so the new tabs are not the ones in focus).

**CONCLUSION:**

Would like to do this on Chrome, Firefox, Safari (Mac), and Edge (Windows 10), but info for even a single browser is helpful.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = FALSE 'This is the one I think should solve your issues
IE.Navigate "YourURLHere"
```